# Can't see detailed errors with Azure emulator

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, iis-express, azure-emulator

I have an Azure Cloud Service, with two web roles - one MVC, one Web Api. When I debug, it's running on Azure compute / storage emulator. I'm using IIS Express 7.5.

Both were working fine until I updated to Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and Azure SDK 2.4. Now the MVC web role is fine, but the Web Api role just says 'The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.'

I have tried adding:

```
 <customErrors mode="Off" />
```

and

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

to the web.config, but to no avail. Where else can I try?

Comment: Have you tried Azure Diagnostics - a quick look at the Application Log will throw up clues.  In addition, you have tried to remotely access the machine?  Again, you'll get some of the logs as well as being able to attempt your connection on the local machine which will provide a more meaningful answer.  Finally, check you haven't left another customError in your config...

Comment: I think it was a problem with Azure Diagnostics, actually - perhaps a versioning issue. I removed the trace listener in the web.config. and it all worked OK again. Thanks!